# "if else" statement repeating first value in statement instead of calculating for each

Tags: r

I would like to create a new column in a Tibble which determines the contribution from each mobility score to an index score.

I used the following code:

```
#Add new column for each EQ5D measure contribution
mobility_contribution=if(combined_data$mobility==1){0}else
  if(combined_data$mobility==2){0.058}else 
if(combined_data$mobility==3){0.076}else 
  if(combined_data$mobility==4){0.207}else 
    if(combined_data$mobility==5){0.274}
```

The first row has a mobility score of 4 (i.e. output should be 0.207). However, the new column repeats 0.207 across all subsequent rows, even though the mobility scores change.

How do I fix this?

Thanks!
Kay

Comment: `if (combined_data$mobility==4)`, I have a feeling that this will only check the first element. To get around using a for-loop, you would need some sort of lookup table for this I would get or else apply it as a function

Comment: Hi Dan - is there an easy way to do either one of those? I'm a complete beginner.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an R expert but my intuition would be to try this:

```
mapping <- Vectorize(function(mobility){
    return switch(mobility,0,0.058,0.076,0.207,0.274)
})
```

and then apply this function to your column (this I'm not sure how best to do this for a Tibble but it will be something like this):

```
mobility_contribution <- lapply(combined_data$mobility, mapping)
```

Some links:

- [switch](https://www.datamentor.io/r-programming/switch-function/)
- [lapply](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.1/topics/lapply) (although maybe you need to use the [Tibble](https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-apply-a-function-to-a-matrix-tibble/) method here, I'm not sure)
- [Vectorize](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Vectorize.html)

Comment: Getting the same result and the following Error message:

Warning messages:
1: In if (combined_data$mobility == 1) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (combined_data$mobility == 2) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
3: In if (combined_data$mobility == 3) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
4: In if (combined_data$mobility == 4) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Comment: @Kay yes, I think the issue is that your checks are only checking the first row. See my edit, wrapped up the if-else ladder in a switch statement and that into a function and then apply that function to each element in your column

Comment: Try wrapping your function with `Vectorize`. After that, the function accepts vector arguments.

Comment: @COOLSerdash in the function definition or just in the function call (as shown in the edit)? Or do you mean to replace `lapply`?

Comment: Sorry for not being specific. Try this: 

`mapping <- Vectorize(function(mobility){
    return switch(mobility,0,0.058,0.076,0.207,0.274)
})`

Answer (score 1):

I hope nested ifelse will work

```
mobility_contribution <- ifelse(combined_data$mobility==1,0,ifelse(combined_data$mobility==2,0.058,ifelse(combined_data$mobility==3,0.076,ifelse(combined_data$mobility==4,0.207,0.274))))
```

please try this